# How to use 32bit alpha-blended BMP in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, alpha, blending

Is there any way to use this kind of format in .Net (C#)?
I want to use the same skin format that uTorrent uses in my app, but i can't get the transparent background.
Any ideas?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things:

- Copy your bitmap onto the form as background.
- Call the **UpdateLayeredWindow** (user32.dll) to enable per-pixel alpha transparency.

The code is a liitle bit bulky, but here is a very nice sample application with source code: [Per Pixel Alpha Blend in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/perpxalpha_sharp.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The PixelFormat enumeration lists the formats of 'bitmaps' you can create in .Net, so you'd want PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat.aspx

However I'm not entirely sure that the BMP file format supports transparency - so you would have to save the file as perhaps a PNG file instead.

Comment: sam is correct.  BMP does not support an alpha channel.  Transparency in bitmaps is usually done the chroma-key way (select one color to be 100% transparent).

PNG will be the optimal choice here.

Answer (score 2):

While the BMP format does support an alpha channel, Windows ignores it. Luckily, the format is rather simple and you can read it using System.IO.BinaryReader then create a Drawing.Bitmap using the LockBits and UnlockBits methods to write the data to it.